# How to get closed form solution of equation for extremum of function involving absolute value

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given the following:
$$
f(t) = at + \frac{1}{2} bt^2 + \lambda |c+t|
$$
I want to find $t$ when
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = 0
$$
I can find
$$
\frac{df}{dt} =
\begin{cases}
a + bt + \lambda & c+t > 0 \\
a + bt  & c+t = 0 \\
a + bt - \lambda & c+t < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

setting each case to zero and solving for $t$, then plugging the solution back into the conditions, gives
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = 
\begin{cases}
a + bt + \lambda & c - \frac{a + \lambda}{b} > 0 \\
a + bt  & c - \frac{a}{b} = 0 \\
a + bt - \lambda & c - \frac{a - \lambda}{b} < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

The cases above kind of look like
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = a + bt + \text{sgn}(k)
$$

where $k$ is the condition on the right hand side. However, the condition on the right hand side changes. In fact, the condition itself can be written this way:
$$
k = c - \frac{a + \text{sgn}(k) \lambda}{b}
$$

I have no idea how to solve this last equation. However, I think that maybe I am doing something wrong and there is a better approach to solving the original problem, which is to find **the value of $t$ that makes the derivative with respect to $t$ equal to $0$ in a closed-form solution**.

To be clear, I have a solution above already in terms of cases. I want an answer that can be written as a single formula.

Answer (score 1):

Considering

$$
f(t) = a t+\frac 12 b t^2+\lambda \sqrt{(t+c)^2}
$$

we have

$$
f'=a+b t+\frac{\lambda  (c+t)}{\sqrt{(c+t)^2}} = a+b t+\lambda \sigma(t+c) = 0
$$

and solving for $t$

we have

$$
t^* = -\frac {a+\lambda\sigma(t+c)}{b}
$$

where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is the signum function.

or one of

$$
t^* =  -\frac {a\pm \lambda}{b}
$$

Comment: Yes but now $t$ is a function of the sign of $t$. That isn't helpful because it's like my question where $k$ is a function of the sign of $k$.

Comment: Yes it is a function of $t$ but this function has the value $\pm 1$ Depending on the values for $c$ should be easy to find which is the correct one.

Comment: Finding the correct one involves evaluating cases, which is what I explicitly was hoping to avoid.